# Issues while converting series to const string for plotshape text

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have been trying to print the current volume as  a plotshape text label using the following code...

```
plotshape(EntryCondition, style=shape.labelup, title="Buy flag", location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, text=str.tostring(volume))
```

but I keep getting this error..

> Cannot call 'plotshape' with argument 'text'='call 'str.tostring' (series string)'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to force the `plotshape()` to accept series string, unfortunately.
Use the `label.new()` function instead, which allows to plot and change the text dynamically.

```
if longCondition
    label.new(bar_index, low, str.tostring(volume), color = color.lime, style = label.style_label_up)
```